# How to display data formatted by Draft.js in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a comment box in my React App and I built it with Draft.js as follows. I enter some text and format them with bold and italic buttons. Then I click Comment button. After clicking the Comment button, sendUserComment function will be fired and update the state 'newComment'. AXIOS will send them to the database and return the comment so I can show the comment in the 'newCommentShow' div.

**The problem is, if I type a comment as a text and apply bold, the data will be sent to the database as**
`<p><b>Some texts</b></p>`

and the returning data is processing as the same way. **So I'm seeing the whole `<p><b>Some texts</b></p>` as a string in the 'newCommentShow' div**. How can I process tags in that string and show the correct formatted text?

```
const { Toolbar } = toolbarPlugin;
const plugins = [toolbarPlugin];
const text = '';

class ProjectModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            newComment: '',
            editorState: createEditorStateWithText(text)
        };
        this.editorOnChange = this.editorOnChange.bind(this);
    }

    editorOnChange(editorState) {
        this.setState({ editorState });
    }

    sendUserComment = () => {
        const com = stateToHTML(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent())
         API.post('add_comment', com)
             .then(({ data }) => {
                 console.log(data);
                 this.setState({ newComment: data.comment })
             })
             .catch((err) => {
                 console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
             })
    }

    render() {
      return(
         <div className="newCommentBox">                            
            <div className="newCommentMain">
              <Toolbar>
                {
                 (externalProps) => (
                   <div className="toolbarModal">
                      <BoldButton {...externalProps} />                                                                                                
                      <ItalicButton {...externalProps} />                                                                                           
                   </div>                                                                                        
                 )                                                                                    
                }                                                                                
              </Toolbar>                                                                                
              <Editor                                                                                    
                editorState={this.state.editorState}                                                                                    
                onChange={this.editorOnChange}                                                                                    
                plugins={plugins}                                                                                    
                ref={(element) => { this.editor = element; }}                                                                                    
                className="editor"                                                                                
              />                                                                            
            </div>                                                                               
            <button className="commentBtn" onClick={() => this.sendUserComment}>Comment</button>   

            <div className="newCommentShow">{this.state.newComment}</div>                                                                         
         </div>         
      )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject HTML directly into a React component can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
<div className="newComment" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.newComment }} />
```

Note - as per the docs, use this feature with caution and be sure you do not leave yourself vulnerable to [XSS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.